# Wait for process start

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

So what I am attempting to do is start explorer from my program then pop my application back in front of explorer or just start explorer behind my application...

Currently I have explorer starting then I have actions to bring my application to the front but explorer can take a few seconds to start and that messes up my whole chain of events.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.FileName = environmentVariable + "\\explorer.exe";
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.uxMainFolder.Text) ? this.uxMainFolder.Text + "\\" + path2 : Path.Combine("R:\\Project", path2);

 try
 {
      process.Start();

      this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
      this.Show();
      this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
 }
 finally
 {
      process.Dispose();
 }
```

Any light you can shed on this problem would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** I'm looking for some event that I can call TopMost or my minimized/show/normal approach on after explorer has been loaded.

The program generates a project directory with all of the required documents for each project type the pops up that directory in explorer.

This is meant as a quality of life change for users wanting to create 10 or 20 projects at one sitting.

Comment: If you can tell us about the *problem* for which "start explorer behind my application" is your proposed *solution*, we might be able to offer more constructive assistance.

Comment: don't think there is other way then "guessing", if you have no some reliable output from that process that all data was initialized and it runs normally (can be some cout, file created in some specific place...)

Comment: Is the TopMost property on the form not what you're looking for?

Comment: "*pop my application back in front of explorer or just start explorer behind my application*" This statement does not make much sense, nothing can be "in front of" or "behind" explorer, the only visible elements Explorer normally has is the task bar and any directory windows. [Please explain the problem you are trying to solve not the problem with the solution to the problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm looking for some event that I can call TopMost or my minimized/show/normal approach on after explorer has been loaded. The reason I'm trying to do this is it was the main complaint about my program which generates a project directory with all of the required documents for each project type the problem with my current implantation is that they may want to create 10 or 20 projects at one sitting and I thought this would be a simple quality of life change.

Comment: None of the things you're talking about in your explanation have any obvious relationship to an Explorer window. E.g. "generates a project directory" - what does that have to do with an Explorer window?

Comment: After the project directory is created they have to move any communications, non-standard documents over to the directory or changes in scope over to their various folders in the directory. So there is a rational reason to pop up the explorer window after creation.

Comment: But how do they do that if you've placed the window behind your application window? To be honest, this mostly sounds like what you have is "create directory, open window, do lots more manipulation, then the user can take over and do things", when what you should change to is "create directory, do lots more manipulation, *now* open the window and then the user can take over and do things"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Ugly Way

Generally, when waiting for a process to finish loading, you would call

```
Process.WaitForInputIdle()
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2.aspx) :

> Causes the Process component to wait indefinitely for the associated process to enter an idle state. This overload applies only to processes with a user interface and, therefore, a message loop.

With `explorer.exe` this will most likely not work, as this process often spawns a child process and instantly dies.

The workaround would be to launch the process, `Sleep` for say, 250-500ms, then find the new `Process` using some godawful hack, and then call `WaitForInputIdle` on that `Process`.

### An Alternative

If you are willing to start `explorer.exe` minimized, you could do it like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "explorer.exe";
psi.Arguments = "/separate";
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Either this or register the LostFocus event on your form for a short period before starting the process.  I.e. register a new LostFocus event that will set focus back to your form in the event you lose focus, start the process, start a timer who's sole purpose is to remove the LostFocus event you just registered after 500ms or some other arbitrary time.

Comment: @wilso132 Why not write that as an answer?

Comment: it's too ugly for an "answer". :)